# Trying to stop animation when starting a new activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

There's a ton of questions on SO that ask about stopping the animation when starting a new activity and I'm just having no luck. Am I doing something wrong that is blatantly obvious? Thanks in advance.

```
public void onClick (View view) {
Intent about = new Intent(this, about.class);
        about.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        startActivity(about);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`.

This is when you start a new activity.

`Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, about.class);
    aboutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    aboutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(aboutIntent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);`

When you press back button, you will be still shown animation. To remove this animation, you have to add `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` to onPause method of the activity on which you pressed back button.